# Can I allow my author's to change their gravatar to a custom image?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, logic, blogs

I am new to WordPress themeing, I am creating one theme from scratch and don't want to use any plugin to achieve this.

Can I allow my blog author's to change their gravatar to a custom image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, First, you need to visit Settings » Discussion page and scroll down to Avatars section. This is where you can configure and change gravatar settings on your WordPress site.

[image]

You will notice that there are a few choices available under the default avatar option. These avatars are used when a user does not have a gravatar associated with their email address.

Out of the box WordPress uses the mystery person icon as the default gravatar. You can change that to blank or gravatar logo.

There are few other options available as well. These are automatically generated images in different designs. These images use comment author’s name or email address to mathematically generate a unique gravatar image.

Don’t forget to click on the save changes button after changing your default gravatar.

You can read more [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-gravatar-on-wordpress/)

Comment: need a custom image, profile picture, not defaults :(

Comment: wanna do this, without plugin https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-an-authors-photo-in-wordpress/

Comment: I think you need to create your own function using the default wordpress gravatar hooks https://www.hungred.com/how-to/customize-wordpress-avatar-filter-hook/

Comment: Thanks, I tried but that is only for single author website.

Comment: You can pass various parameters on that hook. For example, you can pass another author's ID on the said filter  ```function site_get_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt){
    //$avatar format includes the tag <img>
    $imgpath = "http://website.com/image/myownimage.jpg";
    $my_avatar = "<img src='".$path."' alt='".$alt."' height='".$size."' width='".$size."' />";
    return $my_avatar;
} ```